# Vue.Js how to get value of prop attribute with id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, relationship

I've been stuck on this for a while now and i'm not sure what to Google to find a solution and through the vuejs docs but can't find anything usefull.

Basicly I have a app with a few props. One of them is 'soundpacks'. This prop is setup this way in my app.js:

```
soundpacks: [
    { 
        title: 'Techno soundpack',
        tempo: 130,
        genre_id: 1,
        teacher_id: 1
    },
    { 
        title: 'Deep House soundpack',
        tempo: 123,
        genre_id: 2,
        teacher_id: 2
    }
]
```

As you can see I have declared a genre_id in here. I have another prop declared like this:

```
genres: [
    {
        id: 1,
        label: 'Techno'
    }, 
    {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Deep House'
    }
]
```

My problem is as follows. On my front-page I want to display all the soundpacks in a div which I do with a v-for. This is working but in this div I want to display the name of the genre that is linked to the soundpack through the genre_id. I have no clue on how to get this label value to display in this v-for and i'm hoping anybody can give me a push in the good direction. I'm new to Vue.Js thats why I'm asking what looks to be a very simple problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What about a simple lookup? https://jsfiddle.net/c0z82hy5/

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a computed property that you can add to your component.
Will compute a new list that you can directly use to display in your app.

```
computed: {
    computeListData(){
        let newList = []
        this.soundpacks.forEach((item) => {
            let data = this.genres.filter((genre) => {
                return (genre.id === item.genre_id)
            })
            let listData = item
            listData.label = data[0].label
            newList.push(listData)
        })
        return newList
    }
}
```

Here's a gist link that you can refer to:
https://gist.github.com/ayushgupta11/7eeb1a4fdfeadab1a94a1e592ecd53dd

Please tell if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of options here.

Just using a template you can achieve this using nested loops:

```
<div v-for="pack in soundpacks">
    {{ pack.title }} -
    <template v-for="genre in genres">
        <template v-if="genre.id === pack.genre_id">
            {{ genre.label }}
        </template>
    </template>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use a computed property to add the genre label to your soundpack data:

```
computed: {
    extendedSoundpacks () {
        return this.soundpacks.map(pack => {
            const genre = this.genres.find(genre => genre.id === pack.genre_id)

            return {
                // Copy the original object to avoid mutating it.
                // Alternatively you could just nest the object by
                // removing the three dots, though this would be at
                // the expense of a more complicated template.
                ...pack,
                label: genre.label
            }
        })
    }
}
```

While this is slightly better than the loop in the template it still uses nested looping. Better would be to prepare a map to do a quick lookup of the label from the id:

```
computed: {
    genreMap () {
        const genreMap = {}

        this.genres.forEach(genre => {
            // If genres have more than just a label you could store
            // the whole object instead of just the label
            genreMap[genre.id] = genre.label
        })

        return genreMap
    }
}
```

Now we've got `genreMap`, the `find` in my earlier `extendedSoundpacks` example becomes just:

```
const genre = this.genreMap[pack.genre_id]
```

Whilst the code isn't much shorter it does avoid the nested looping, which would be much faster if the arrays are large enough.

However, once you have `genreMap` it becomes pretty trivial to do this in the template without creating a new array of soundpacks:

```
{{ genreMap[pack.genre_id] }}
```

In this case that would be sufficient but if the logic were more complicated than a simple id/label lookup you could use a method...

```
{{ getGenreLabel(pack.genre_id) }}
```

... or a filter:

```
{{ pack.genre_id | genreLabel }}
```

These would need to be defined as functions in the `methods` or `filters` sections of your component respectively. If you needed to use this logic across multiple components you might consider registering the filter globally.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li v-for="soundpack in soundpacks" :key="soundpack.teacher_id">
   {{genres[soundpack.genre_id - 1].label}} 
</li>
```

Note that the -1 is because you started your indexing at 1 while the index of an array starts at 0, also note that my code only works if you continue a constant numbering of your genres.

Comment: And what happens, when the order of the genres differs from the order in the array?